# 7-Zip to decompress selected files by batch file

Tags: batch-processing, 7zip

I try create Batch file to simplify operations with *.zip archive containing electrical part informations for eCAD system (i.e. Altium Designer)
I use zip files from WWW that provides components models. Usually I download tens of these files for import to eCAD. Each Zip file comes with lot of mess,so only few files-extracted are useable.

**ZIP has usual structure (example)**
PARTNAME.zip has content :
.PARTNAME/ dir
..PADS/ sub-dir
There are files ending with *.d *.p *.c and *.asc

I try to extract these 4 files only to %WorkingDir% directory specified in Batch file.

```
...
set ZipApp=C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z" e LIB.zip -o%WorkingDir% -r -i*.d -i*.p -i*.c -i*.asc
...
```

Ends with Incorrect wildcard typer marker *.d

In future I also do this recursively for each *.ZIP archive in current directory.

Thanks you for hints...

Comment: *Very* borderline programming-related (the fact you're doing a batch file) but I'll answer anyway. I wouldn't hold out too much hope on the question surviving for long though :-)

Answer (score 0):

You either have to specify a list file with `@` or a wildcard with `!`. Hence your command should be:

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z" e LIB.zip -o%WorkingDir% -r -i!*.d -i!*.p -i!*.c -i!*.asc
```

This is detailed in the help text you get when you run `7z` with no arguments, the relevant bit being:

```
-i[r[-|0]]{@listfile|!wildcard} : Include filenames
                     ^
                    here
```

Comment: `Command Line Error : Unknown Switch -`  by Directory name in variable %WorkingDir% , `C:\KPR - Altium pr├íce\Libraries\Working` ... maybe I should rename to English

Comment: @KPr, that's possibly a good idea but I think what's causing *this* issue is the presence of `-` in you path and the very basic substitution that takes place: `-oC:\KPR - Altium...` - that "naked" `-` is being seen as a command line option, as can be seen with `set xx=aa - bb` then `7z a -o%xx%`, giving that exact error message. You may find that `-o"%WorkingDir%"` will suffice.